# What are the origins of Naruto's stomach's double tetragram seal?

Tags: naruto

The center pattern looks like an Aztec symbol for rebirth but I'm wondering: How did Kishimoto come up with this exactly?[image]

Comment: Can you provide an image of the aztec symbol?

Answer (score 3):

I can't seem to find any official information as to where the [Eight Trigrams Sealing Style](https://naruto.fandom.com/wiki/Eight_Trigrams_Sealing_Style) originated or was based on.

However, here's a theory.

As you may know, *Naruto* has many influences from Buddhism and Hinduism: [the Multiple Lotus Nonself Connected Cannons](https://naruto.fandom.com/wiki/Multiple_Lotus_Nonself_Connected_Cannons), [The Six Paths of Pain](https://naruto.fandom.com/wiki/Six_Paths_of_Pain), [Formation of Ten Thousand Snakes](https://naruto.fandom.com/wiki/Formation_of_Ten_Thousand_Snakes) and the [Chakra](https://naruto.fandom.com/wiki/Chakra), to name a few, were based on Buddhist and Hinduist beliefs.

With that, I say that it's possible it might be inspired from the [Dharmachakra](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dharmachakra) or the wheel of Dhamma. A comparison of the seals are shown below: [image]

According to Wikipedia, it is connected to the [Four Noble Truths](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Four_Noble_Truths) and the [Noble Eightfold Path](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Noble_Eightfold_Path), both of which are teachings to help a person escape the painful cycle of rebirth, if I understand correctly.